# Access service on kuberntes using hostname instead of ip Address

Tags: kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-ingress, hostname, istio-gateway

I am using istio ingress gateway for one of my services, which has to be exposed to http requests. I have configured gateway(myservice-gatewa) and virtual service(myservice-endpoints).  I am able to access service using http://{ingress_ip}:{ingress_port}/{path}. But I want to access service using host name instead of any ip address. how do I do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a DNS name already pointing at the ingress gateway (maybe it was created as part of a LoadBalancer-type service in the `istio-system` namespace)?  Do your virtual services have appropriate `host:` settings?  What URL do you want to be able to call, and what happens when you call it with your current setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze have defined host as mainservice.example.com. While trying to access this service as http://mainservice.example.com:80/{some path} I am getting Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mainservice.example.com in postman

Comment: That sounds like your external DNS isn't correctly configured to reach the ingress gateway.  That'll be a cluster-level setup issue, though, and not the sort of programming question Stack Overflow is good at answering.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, You want to access your service from within your cluster via host name and not via IP ( Assuming service is of type NodePort). If yes have you considered looking up the Kubernetes documentation on DNS for Services and Pods?

Comment: The Istio ingress gateway would be a way to receive calls from outside the cluster, somewhat similar to the Kubernetes Ingress system; individual Services would still be `type: ClusterIP`.

Comment: @Amit. i have already explored dns option and found out of the k8 doesn't support my requirement. So I had to go for istio ingress gateway.